# How to extract only the foreground using the given mask?

Tags: python, opencv, mask, extract, foreground

I have the original image and its mask (I don't have to create one using opencv), I would like to use opencv to extract the foreground with the provided mask.

[image: real image] 
[image: mask]

I want to extract only the human into a new image (where the human mask is given)

Comment: what do you mean by "only extract"? You want an image with black or transparent background, where all the mask image's pixels are set to the original image's pixels and the background stays black/transparent? Images are always rectangular, so it is not clear what you mean by "extract only that mask region"

Comment: I think you should first understand how edge detection is performed and work from there. That way, you can try and trace an edge which separates your object in the foreground from objects in the background.  Here's a nice little introduction. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html

Comment: hello guys, I need to extract the human figure alone into a new image (with maybe transparent pixels as the background)